# Python how to "use" the return of a function

Tags: python, list, api, return

Beginner Question beware

So basically I am using an API to get certain Data, in this case a dealID.

I am using following code:

`resp = service.get_deal_data( size=1, level=None, limit_distance=None, limit_level=None)`

Size, level etc do not matter.

So the api call returns this output:

```
{'date': '2022-09-20T13:35:42.042',
 'status': 'OPEN',
 'reason': 'SUCCESS',
 'dealReference': 'MKPYFDNLMCCTYNK',
 'dealId': 'DIAAAAKMH5HGMA8',
 'affectedDeals': [{'dealId': 'DIAAAAKMH5HGMA8', 'status': 'OPENED'}],
 'level': 0.99663,
 'size': 1.0,}
```

My question is how do I get the data from the output to use it in another function

I want to get the DealID and continue to use it without inputting manually.

F.e.:

I want to compare the deal ID to a list of IDs and return a warning if it already is on the list.

```
list = [DDHWUH5HGMA8,JNDWJ7HDJ2, 7HDWUDH9D, ...]

if dealId in list:
    print("exist")
else:
    print("not exist")
```

returns following error:

NameError: name 'dealId' is not defined

Comment: I see you have posted some code which assigns a value to `resp`. You don't show anything else which uses this variable. Is there some other code you can share with us?

Comment: Ah I forgot to add that after assigning resp = service.get_deal... I am using just resp to use the function if that makes sense
so the code is
"resp = service.get_deal_data( size=1, level=None, limit_distance=None, limit_level=None)"
"resp"

Comment: Also "print (resp[dealId])" gives the same name error

Comment: So, you've tried that? If so, you should update your question with that code, plus the full error traceback it produces.

Comment: Use `'dealId'` instead.

Comment: A couple of things.
1. `list` is a reserved word in Python, so don't use it for variable names.
2. Once you get the response, you have to get the data you require from that. so here I am getting the deal id like `resp.get("dealId")`. This will only work is the returned data ie. response is of type Dict. If it's purely json string, then you have to `import json` and do something like `dict_data = json.loads(response)`

Comment: If you don't know what type a return value is, you can use `type()` function. in this case it seems to be a dictionary. If one day you have an unknown object and no doc, you can use `dir()` to list object's functions and attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API result is the type of dictionary, then
Try doing :

```
list = [DDHWUH5HGMA8,JNDWJ7HDJ2, 7HDWUDH9D, ...]

if resp['dealID'] in list:
    print("exist")
else:
    print("not exist")
```